# Point me in the right direction on NLP datastructures and search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, nlp

I've got a school assignment to make a language analyzer that's able to guess the language of an input. The assignment states this has to be done by pre-parsing language defined texts and making statistics about letters used, combinations of letter etc and then making a guess based on this data.

The data structure we're supposed to use is simple multi-dimensional hashtables but I'd like to take this opportunity to learn a bit more about implementing structures etc. What'd I'd like to know is what to read up about. My knowledge of algorithms is very limited but I'm keen on learning if someone could point me in the right direction.

Without any real knowledge and just reading up on different posts I'm currently planing on studying undirected graphs as a datastructure for letter combinations (and somehow storing the statistics within the graph as well) and boyer-moore for the per-word search algorithm.

Am I totally on the wrong track and these would be impossible to implement in this situation or is there something else superior for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your hands on a copy of Cormen et al. "Introduction to Algorithms"

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Second-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262032937](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)

It's a very very good book to read up on data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

[Language detection using character trigrams](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/326576-language-detection-using-character-trigrams/)